# Get Certificates in Keychain

Tags: cocoa, security, macos, keychain, appkit

I've looked over the Security framework documentation but I can't seem to be able to find a way to get all of the certificates on a given keychain. Are there methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After mining the documentation, header files, and source files, I’ve come up with the following code:

```
#import <Security/Security.h>

- (void)logMessageForStatus:(OSStatus)status
               functionName:(NSString *)functionName
{
    CFStringRef errorMessage;
    errorMessage = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL);
    NSLog(@"error after %@: %@", functionName, (NSString *)errorMessage);
    CFRelease(errorMessage);  
}

- (void)listCertificates
{
    OSStatus status;
    SecKeychainSearchRef search = NULL;

    // The first argument being NULL indicates the user's current keychain list
    status = SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes(NULL,
        kSecCertificateItemClass, NULL, &search);

    if (status != errSecSuccess) {
        [self logMessageForStatus:status
                     functionName:@"SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes()"];
        return;
    }

    SecKeychainItemRef searchItem = NULL;

    while (SecKeychainSearchCopyNext(search, &searchItem) != errSecItemNotFound) {
        SecKeychainAttributeList attrList;
        CSSM_DATA certData;

        attrList.count = 0;
        attrList.attr = NULL;

        status = SecKeychainItemCopyContent(searchItem, NULL, &attrList,
            (UInt32 *)(&certData.Length),
            (void **)(&certData.Data));

        if (status != errSecSuccess) {
            [self logMessageForStatus:status
                         functionName:@"SecKeychainItemCopyContent()"];
            CFRelease(searchItem);
            continue;
        }

        // At this point you should have a valid CSSM_DATA structure
        // representing the certificate

        SecCertificateRef certificate;
        status = SecCertificateCreateFromData(&certData, CSSM_CERT_X_509v3,
            CSSM_CERT_ENCODING_BER, &certificate);

        if (status != errSecSuccess) {
            [self logMessageForStatus:status
                         functionName:@"SecCertificateCreateFromData()"];
            SecKeychainItemFreeContent(&attrList, certData.Data);
            CFRelease(searchItem);
            continue;
        }

        // Do whatever you want to do with the certificate
        // For instance, print its common name (if there's one)

        CFStringRef commonName = NULL;
        SecCertificateCopyCommonName(certificate, &commonName);
        NSLog(@"common name = %@", (NSString *)commonName);
        if (commonName) CFRelease(commonName);

        SecKeychainItemFreeContent(&attrList, certData.Data);
        CFRelease(searchItem);
    }

    CFRelease(search);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dylan Cheers. Consider filing an enhancement request radar (or three, actually) with Apple: this could be sample code, this could be in the Security Programming Guide, and they could provide a simpler, Cocoa-based API for this.

Comment: The `searchItem` returned by `SecKeychainSearchCopyNext` is already a `SecCertificateRef`. (You are looking for items in the certificate class, so every result is a certificate item.) It isn't necessary to extract and reinterpret its data: a simple typecast will get better results.

Comment: will it work for iOS? 
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnRef,
          (id)kSecMatchLimitOne, kSecMatchLimit,
          ( id)kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
          nil];
 
 CFTypeRef result = NULL;
 SecItemCopyMatching(( CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);
 NSLog(@"%@", ( id)result);

returns me null.

Comment: Any possible solution for iOS devices?

Answer (score 16):

If you target Mac OS 10.6 or later, you can use `SecItemCopyMatching` to easily query the keychain:

```
SecKeychainRef keychain = ...
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass, 
                       [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)keychain], kSecMatchSearchList,
                       kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnRef,
                       kSecMatchLimitAll, kSecMatchLimit,
                       nil];
NSArray *items = nil;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&items);
if (status) {
    if (status != errSecItemNotFound)
        LKKCReportError(status, @"Can't search keychain");
    return nil;
}
return [items autorelease]; // items contains all SecCertificateRefs in keychain
```

Note that you must not use this to implement certificate validation — the presence of a CA certificate in a keychain does not indicate that it is trusted to sign certificates for any particular policy.  See the *Certificate, Key, and Trust Programming Guide* to learn how to do certificate validation with the Keychain.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH205-SW1

Comment: This is a great answer, since `SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes` and `SecKeychainSearchCopyNext` are deprecated as of 10.7. This does require some crazy casts to work with ARC, but using a `CFMutableDictionaryRef` and setting these keys works just as well. Thanks!