# How to generate alerts before Apple certificates expire?

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, keychain, apple-developer

When a production Push Notification Certificate expires, push notifications stop working for live apps. Apple emails the account's Agent before the date comes but the developer might not be the Agent of the account and miss the email and the alert... and guess what? that just happened to me :-)

Currently I'm adding events to my calendar to remind me before it happens, but this is a very error prone system!

I was wondering if is there any method to periodically scan for installed certs on a mac and alert if a date is coming (I can download all certs from the dev portal an install on my mac).

I've tried to do so with Access Keychain, but it doesn't have that option. Maybe you use a script or something similar?

Comment: You should see this article helping to get all installed certificates from keychain on mac 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767957/get-certificates-in-keychain
i hope after you get certificates you can also get their expiry and set a local event to it .. :)